# filter result applies on first pagination only

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a model which I am filtering based on some parameters given by the user. The filtering works just fine but once I start using pagination, only the records from the first page are filtered and the others are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array of query variables to the paginator to keep them in the links.

```
$collection = $query->paginate();
$collection->appends(['key' => 'value', /* ... add your filters here */]);
```

See `Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator::appends` in the Laravel source code.